# AmCharts - version in code?

Tags: javascript, version-control, amcharts

Is there a way to tell the version of AmCharts library that is running, from within the code, like on the AmCharts runtime object? Or any other way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found it. Just search for this.version within the minified source of amcharts.js.

Answer (score 15):

Or, you can find out by typing this into the browser console on page with a chart:

```
AmCharts.charts[0].version
```